# Error inserting new registers on MySQL DB with Flask

Tags: python, mysql, angular, database, flask

I am looking for your help because i am getting this error on Python Flask:

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Autoevaluacion', 'RT_Funcionarios', 'Reporteadores', 'Reporteadores_Gerentes', '' at line 1")
```

I am inserting data from Angular in my MySQL DB with the help of Flask, i am trying to insert the fields name, email, role and foros, this last one is filled with the elements of an array so when i tried to save the data, that error is shown.

this is my python code

```
@app.route('/insertarUsuario', methods = ["POST"])
def insertar_usuario():
    conection = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'root','root', 'users')
    data = request.json
    print(data)
    print(data['foros'])
    cursor = conection.cursor() 
    sql_query ="INSERT INTO administrador_usuarios(nombre, email, rol, foros) VALUES ('" + str(data["nombre"]) + "','"+ str(data["email"])+"','"+str(data["rol"])+"', '"+ str(data["foros"])+"')"
    cursor.execute(sql_query)
    conection.commit()
    response = "OK"
    print("respuesta:",response)
    return jsonify(response)
```

I would like to highlight 2 things:

1-. that array that will fill the field foros, it comes from the number of foros you select through checkboxes, so if i just check one, the register is saved but if i checked more than one, it crashes.

2-. i found out that if i replace

```
(data["foros"])
```

for

```
str("autoevaluacion" + "rt_funcionario")
```

it works so i think maybe it about how do i receive the array.

Can you help me please?. I am kinda new on Flask

Comment: You should be worried if [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) is registering. [more details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: You have a list of data that needs to be inserted into DB?